# How can i replace Interop DLL with Open XML as Interop DLL has access issues in RDS server

Tags: c#, mvvm

We have a .net project (C#) using MVVM . How can i replace Interop DLL with Open XML as Interop DLL has access issues in RDS server.

Below is the code snippet

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document olDoc = _item.MailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document;

tempAppFileName = tempFilePath + @"" + _item.emailIdentifier.ToString() + ".docx";

olDoc.SaveAs2(tempAppFileName);

Comment: A Word document has a proprietary interface if you are using a doc or docx format.  You would have to save the word document in xml format for code to work.  I've have not been too successful in the past using Open Xml with Microsoft products.  Been years since I tried.  Not sure if Microsoft has updated their software to be more compatible with the open xml standard.

Comment: Are you sure Word interop was the best way for this to begin with? You seem to be using Outlook anyway, saving a mailitem as .docx? Wouldn't saving as .msg or html be an option and to ditch Word altogether?